# Install specific rebar3 version on mac

Tags: macos, erlang, port, homebrew, rebar3

I want to use rebar3 with erlang 24. The problem is, that if I install the newest rebar3 version I get the necessity for erlang 25. So I installed erlang 24 first but it did not change anything. I tried to install older rebar3 version with whom erlang 24 is compatible but so far nothing has worked.
I tried port and brew, but they show me only rebar 19 is available for downloads.
When I clone the new rebar3 version from git, and switch to an old commit from rebar16 I cannot install it. Does anyone have any ideas what could work?

Comment: To help you I suggest you share the commands you used when installing and what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of your existing homebrew erlang (if any) then use [kerl](https://github.com/kerl/kerl) to install erlang, and finally build [rebar3](https://github.com/erlang/rebar3) from source.  The thing I like about kerl is you can easily switch between multiple erlang installations.  Here's the jist of it...

```
brew unlink erlang
cd ~/
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kerl/kerl/master/kerl
chmod a+x kerl
./kerl build 24.3.4.7 24.3
mkdir kerlbins
./kerl install 24.3 ~/kerlbins/24.3
. ~/kerlbins/24.3/activate
git clone https://github.com/erlang/rebar3.git
cd rebar3/
./bootstrap
./rebar3 local install
```